# WCF authentication + authorization

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, authorization

We have WCF 4.5 service and we are trying to secure it.

We have users in our database schema but what we want to do is operations like

```
[OperationsContract]
void PostMessage(string message, int userId) 
   //used ID is supposed to be id of user who post message
```

our service is secured with basicHttpsBinding with basic authorization.
I can get username of user who accessed that method with:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

But how can i Add his database Id into PrimaryIdentity.
In other words, How to verify, that he user with username "John" can only send  his userId. What is the best technology to verify him?

Also how it is possible that STATIC variable (Current) is different for each request. We use default WCF instanceMode which is... PerSession. So how it is possible to have static variable different for each request.

It feels pretty lame to query database for userId by his username for each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It feels pretty lame to query database for userId by his username for each request.

I disagree.

In order to provide secure WCF service I would check credentials per request. One way of doing it is to create custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` and override `Validate` method. You should also configure your `Web.config` to use your custom validator.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GeneralBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WCFApp.UserNamePassValidator, WCFApp" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: And thats exactly what i do. BUT what if... imagine that... one user create account and i verify him against db... its ok then... but WHAT if he is really mean and send me in userId property some different number than his own id. I dont want to go to DB AGAIN just for his user id by his name i get from ServiceSecurityContext.

Comment: Then you have two options. First one is to secure your client to permit passing ID different than the current logged user account ID. Second,  a better because is more secure is to validate ID and `ServiceSecurityContext` username in your `PostMessage` method. One more thing, if the case is about security / data integrity executing one more command against database is **nothing** comparing to that someone as you said could send you user ID property different than his own ID.

Comment: OK thats a valid argument. But it just feel lame to go to database twice for the same entity by same key. Once for the passwordValidation and second time for the user id. Both by username.